# Can we use dagger only in some parts of an android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

Until now we have not used dagger in our android app. We want to use dagger for whatever new code that we write in our app from now on. Is this possible ? I just started exploring dagger and i have a doubt if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , It is possible. You can add dagger for ongoing project and use it.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried it ?  Can you give any of your's or other's github repo reference links where dagger is used in only some parts of the app. Or Any article that you came across that explains about this topic.

Comment: Yes, I have implemented it. you can check [This link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/dagger-2-android-example/) for reference.